# define post route without csrf token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to call my functions from android side.

now, I want to send post values from android side.

How can I disable `csrf token` for some functions ?

because without it I got error message .

like this:

```
Route::post('mobile/android/getlastnews','NewsController@getLastNews');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Laravel5, How to disable VerifycsrfToken middleware for specific route?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223189/in-laravel5-how-to-disable-verifycsrftoken-middleware-for-specific-route)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable CSRF Token in Laravel and why we have to disable it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806762/how-to-disable-csrf-token-in-laravel-and-why-we-have-to-disable-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` and in the `protected $except = [];` array add your URL that you want to be skipped for `CSRF` validation.

Answer (score 6):

For Laravel 5.2, inside `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` you just need to add it to the `$except` array.

```php
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'mobile/android/getlastnews'
    ];
}
```

If you wanted to allow all routes for `mobile/` you can do the following

```php
protected $except = [
    'mobile/*'
];
```