# Ajax request on Controller fails

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have a problem with the following code in Laravel. I need to send some variables to my controller, do something with them and return three variables back. I made have made the ajax call, the route and the controller but the ajax call fail. As an error code [I receive this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOBGU.png).

**View**

```
function gg() {
    var slider_value  = document.getElementById('paradnyi').value;
    var checkbox_value  = document.getElementById('check_box').value;
    var dto = {slider_value : slider_value, checkbox_value : checkbox_value};
    $.ajax({
        url : "/calc_change",
        contentType : 'application/json',
        data : JSON.stringify(dto),
        type : 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById('visits').innerHTML = data[0];
            document.getElementById('slaves').innerHTML = data[1];
        },
        error:  function(xhr, str){
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
        }
    });
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::post('/calc_change',['uses'=>'PagesController@calc_change','as'=>'calc_change']);
```

**Controller**

```
public function calc_change(Request $request){
    $data = array();
    $data[]=1;
    $data[]=2;
    //dd($data);
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Comment: Try `xhr.responseText` instead the `responseCode`.

Comment: @giannischristofakis , it return me html code, at what I found this -  <a title="/Users/user/work/buh_report/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68"><strong>VerifyCsrfToken.php</strong> (line 68)</a></span></td>                                 

its problem with csrf token? how fix it?

Comment: I fix it! I just put 

protected $except = [
        'upload-image',
        'calc_change',
    ];

at VerifyCsrfToken middleware

Comment: You can also use a `get` method instead of a `post` I think it will work to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Laravel5, How to disable VerifycsrfToken middleware for specific route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223189/in-laravel5-how-to-disable-verifycsrftoken-middleware-for-specific-route)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this code before ajax call in jquery section

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```