# The POST method is not supported for route auth/apple/callback. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Sign in with Apple

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on sign in with apple API in laravel 10. But redirect url is giving this error "The POST method is not supported for route auth/apple/callback. Supported methods: GET, HEAD".

I am using get method on route. I also tried "POST" method but then it give 419 page expired error.
I am using ngrok for redirect url as apple does not support http request for redirect url.

These are my routes

```
Route::middleware(['web'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('auth/apple', [AppleLoginController::class,'redirectToApple']);
    Route::get('auth/apple/callback', [AppleLoginController::class,'handleAppleCallback']);
});
```

And these are controller methods

```
public function redirectToApple()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('apple')->redirect();
    }

    
    public function handleAppleCallback()
    {
        try {
            $appleUser = Socialite::driver('apple')->user();
            $user = User::where('apple_id', $appleUser->id)->orWhere('email', $appleUser->email)->first();
            // If the user doesn't exist, create a new user
            $uuid = Uuid::uuid4();
            if (!$user) {
                $new_user = User::updateOrCreate(['email' => $appleUser->email], [
                    'name' => $appleUser->name,
                    'apple_id' =>$appleUser->id,
                    'u_id' => substr($uuid->toString(), 0, 16),
                    'password' => encrypt(Str::random())
                ]);
            }
            Auth::login($new_user ?? $user);
            event(new Registered($new_user));
            return response()->success("Login Successfull");

        } catch (InvalidStateException $e) {
            return response()->error($e->getMessage(), 'Apple Sign-In Failed');
        }
    }
```

This is redirect url in .env file

```
APPLE_REDIRECT_URI=https://f41e-2407-d000-d-25ae-70b2-4bc-d133-5396.ngrok-free.app/auth/apple/callback
```

Comment: Apple/socialite shouldn't ever perform a POST request to your callback URL, how are you handling authentication on your frontend?

Comment: I don't have front-end. I hit the first url http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/apple. It work fine and redirect me to apple sign in page , I enter my email and password but when i click submit button it thorw error. I am testing it locally.

Comment: Is this only for apple? What happens if you use other SNS like google? At first glance there is no problem with the code.

Comment: Google is working fine.

Comment: @ayazBAM You're right, Apple does make a POST request to your callback URL as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/configuring_your_webpage_for_sign_in_with_apple#3331292)

Comment: A few days ago it worked perfectly fine when I implemented it, but when I tried yesterday it started giving errors.

Comment: _"I also tried "POST" method but then it give 419 page expired error."_ - that's most likely an issue with the CSRF protection. Since you probably won't be able to get Apple to pass a valid CSRF token with that POST request, you might have to disable CSRF protection for that route.

Comment: ok let me try it.

Comment: The problem got solved thank you all for your valuable time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Laravel 5, How to disable VerifycsrfToken middleware for specific route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223189/in-laravel-5-how-to-disable-verifycsrftoken-middleware-for-specific-route)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the callback route `auth/apple/callback` support the POST method.

As you mentioned, you will run into issues with CSRF verification. To get around this, you will have to exclude your route from CSRF verification in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` using the `except` property.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $except = [
        "auth/apple/callback"
    ];
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223189/in-laravel-5-how-to-disable-verifycsrftoken-middleware-for-specific-route